# ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: support, android-app

I just noticed this stack trace by chance while debugging another app.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992676/i-cant-get-rid-of-this-error-message-activity-app-name-has-leaked-servicecon) on SO might help to solve it.

```
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@42a64ee0 that was originally bound here
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@42a64ee0 that was originally bound here
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:982)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:876)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1719)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1708)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:480)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:158)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:146)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.restoreAccountsIfNeeded(AccountServiceProxy.java:135)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$11.run(ExchangeService.java:4454)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:980)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:977)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-01 16:51:58.401: E/ActivityThread(23590):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this post, please note it is about the Stack Exchange Android app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaking something this has nothing to do with our android app. This typically happens when Exchange Services (mail) are enabled on an android emulator.

Comment: Ooooh my bad! When I read exchange I assumed it was Stack Exchange. But come to think of it, the package name does start with `com.android` so you're right. This is from a real device by the way.